# Component to add arbitrary number of input fields?

Tags: android, android-widget

I apologize if I'm just missing the obvious.  I'm fairly new to Android development, and while I searched for this particular topic, I wasn't exactly sure what to look for (in terms of a "name").

In an application I'm writing, I have a section where the user can enter the names of players.  However, this can range anywhere from 1 to whatever, no limit.  However, I'm not sure what the best approach for this kind of feature is, or if there's a component that already does something like it.

Basically, the functionality I'm looking for is similar to what you can see in the Edit Contact screen of the phone book; for the phone numbers and email addresses, you can push a little plus button to add a new number/address, or hit the little minus button to remove a number/address.

I can think of several ways to potentially implement this, but in the end I think wrapping it in a custom component would be best (so that you could call "Get Players" and have it return a list of strings by going through each of the inputs and getting the values).

Am I just overthinking this?  Is there a component that does that already?  Is there some example code that demonstrates a good way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with some ideas, I came across a solution that I think will suit what I'm doing.  I created a custom component extending LinearLayout.  As part of the creation of the component, it creates a row that says "Add new..." with a plus-sign button.  Pressing the plus sign button then creates a new row containing an EditText and a minus-button which will remove the row.

I then created a method for this component called getTexts() which returns a List that has all the non-empty Text values from all the components.  Testing it in a dummy app, it seemed to work fine.

I think I need to make tweaks to make it more robust (like the ability to add rows programatically, listeners to alert other components when a row is added/removed, and the ability to set the individual EditText values, for instance), but this functions as I imagined.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) and add a [menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) with a "Add Players" option? You could customize the list view to have a little checkbox, for example, and then begin the game by pressing the menu ... or add new players dynamically by pressing another menu button.

Comment: That's one of the options I've thought about, but while functionally similar, it's not quite the same (and is a little less "user friendly").  I think a ListView may be the way to go, though, with the first row having a label and the plus button and the rest having EditText and a minus button.

Comment: You could also use autocomplete, like when you type in multiple recipients to an email (with the Gmail app) or a text message.

Comment: Hmm, that's a thought; but would that work if the players names you wish to add aren't in your contact list (or whatever list you are pulling the names from)?

Comment: Well then you add a button somewhere to add new players/contacts :) -- just like the phone, the autocomplete doesn't have to actually work. you can just as effectively type in someone's phone number.

Comment: I started looking into that, but it turned out to not quite be the functionality I was looking for, unfortunately.  Similar, but not quite.  But I appreciate the idea, if nothing else it got the brain-juices flowing.